# Twitter bootstrap accordion-heading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to obtain the following effect using twitter bootstrap. One link for the collapse action, and another link for a different action:

[image: example]

Right now I'm getting this by setting the another link with a pull-right class and padding the item. Is there a better way?

Here's the code that matters (sorry but it's in jade, either way I think it's easily understood)

```
div.accordion-heading
    div.row-fluid
        div.span6
            a.accordion-toggle(href="#", data-parent="main-accordion", data-toggle="collapse")= "Collapse Link"
        div.span6
            a.pull-right(style="padding:8px 15px")= "Another Link"
```

Best Regards

Comment: This seems to be the way to do it, for me. Is it not working or are you looking for a different behavior ? Like the whole header toggling the accordion ?

Comment: It's working, and I'm not trying to find a different behavior! I just don't like the "hammered" padding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might get a bit more clean with that :

```
div.accordion-heading
    div.accordion-toggle.group-accordion-toggle
        a(href="#", data-parent="main-accordion", data-toggle="collapse")= "Collapse Link"
        a.pull-right= "Another Link"
```

And that (to avoid the pointer everywhere):

```css
.accordion-toggle.group-accordion-toggle { cursor: inherit; }
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/mMwEV/)